# Optional slug in dynamic route using a folder

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I'm currently working on the internalization of a website using Vue.js and the Nuxt frameworks. 
I'm moving from a page's url being `website.com/my-page` to `website.com/<lang>/my-page`.

To do so, and following the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-routes), I've moved all my pages in a `_lang` folder, giving me the following architecture:

```
pages/
│
└───_lang
│     │ 
|     |__ my-page.vue
|
...
```

This works exactly as intended apart from the fact that the `<lang>` slug is now mandatory, making the access to `website.com/my-page` return a 404.

I would like for this url to show the page in the default language declared in my application.

The only way I found to achieve this is to create another `my-page.vue` at the root of `pages/` containing the following:

```js
<script>
import Mypage from '~/pages/_lang/my-page'
export default Mypage
</script>
```

However, this means creating this kind of alias for every pages of my website, giving me:

```
pages/
│
│─── my-page.vue
│
└───_lang/
│     │ 
|     |__ my-page.vue
|
...
```

Is there any way to make this automate as this is a very tedious process?

Thank you,

Side-note: I've been investigating [extendRoutes](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#extendroutes) without success.

Comment: Really interested in what you ended up doing. Care to share? I’m facing the exact same issues with wanting to map a certain param to my homepage.

Comment: I ended up doing what was suggested by @Aldarund This works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [router-extras-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) module.

```
<router>
    alias:
        - /my-page
</router>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm currently fixing issues when updating the major version of Nuxt lead to all my Stylus css failing with `Error: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.`.
I will try this as soon as everything works fine and report back.

Comment: I completely forgot to report back, I'm sorry. This worked perfectly!

Comment: If the API responses the pageURL as a part of the JSON, how can we use that to create the page path with this API's data ??